# Angular Material 2 Select: avoid comparison by reference

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select, angular-material2

By default angular material 2 select component, makes a comparison by reference with === (equality operator).

I found the implementation [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts): line 600

Is there a way to enforce deep comparison with equality operator over certain object types, or maybe workaround which will compare objects by specific fields.

Thank you

Comment: [**See this issue**](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2785).

Comment: Thank you, but there is just PR which is not merged yet. I need temporal solution while waiting for release which will include this PR.